# Is there an implementation of a visitor of the ANTLR generated parse tree that builds a symbol table?

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr4, visitor-pattern, symbol-table

I'm using ANTLR4 to build the parse tree of a program (C# program, but could be any other popular language). Now I need to resolve the declarations and usages. I know the basic principles (stack of sopes, symbol table...) but I believe this is a fairly common task for there to be an existing implementation. However, I can't find any. If there is one, please guide me. If not, I wonder why.

Note: Ideally, the visitor should be for the ANTLR Parse tree of a C# or javascript/Typescript program, and written in C#. But I don't want to be picky.

Comment: The problem is finding a good symbol table implementation for your language. Parr wrote one in Java (https://github.com/antlr/symtab) but's it's not fully implemented and not a robust design, I guess because it was used in a compiler course he taught. You're probably going to have to write your own. But, once you have that, it's a bit of work to get a tree walker working correctly to work with the symtab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually questions asking for other tools or software is not valid on Stackoverflow, but since I can answer that with a reference to my own work (shameless plug) I will answer it.

In the [ANTLR4 extension for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4) I implemented [a symbol table](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/backend/ContextSymbolTable.ts) and a listener, which fills that. This extension parses ANTLR4 grammars and builds a symbol table with rule/token names, options, alternatives, blocks etc. The symbol table construction happens in the [`DetailsListener` implementation](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/src/backend/DetailsListener.ts).